Trying to add subdomain without an IP address for additional MX records
I was requested to create a sub domain called mail.example.com for email functionality for certain users. I went to my DNS manager where I can add A records. It's asking for an IP address but I don't what to do. This mail.example.com subdomain is only for emails and not tied to any IP addresses. Once I add this A record, I'm going to create a MX record for this email under this sub domain. What should I do?
